# Python 'self' for function

Tags: python, idioms, self

I have read [the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained) on 'self' explained, and I have read the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) on classes. I think I understand the use of `self` in Python classes and the convention therein.

However, being relatively new to Python and its idioms, I cannot understand why some use `self` in a procedural type function definition. For example, in the [Python documentation on integer types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types), the example function is:

```
def bit_length(self):
    s = bin(self)       # binary representation:  bin(-37) --> '-0b100101'
    s = s.lstrip('-0b') # remove leading zeros and minus sign
    return len(s)       # len('100101') --> 6
```

Replacing `self` with `num` is the same functional result; ie:

```
def bit_length(num):
    s = bin(num)       # binary representation:  bin(-37) --> '-0b100101'
    s = s.lstrip('-0b') # remove leading zeros and minus sign
    return len(s)       # len('100101') --> 6
```

There is no idiom like `__init__` etc that I can see here why `self` is being used in the first case. I have seen this use of `self` elsewhere in procedural functions as well, and find it confusing.

So my question: If there is no class or method, why use `self` in a function definition rather than a descriptive parameter name?

Comment: You can find an answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the example bit_length is defined as a function for the int class, so there is actually a 'class or method'. The idea is that you 'ask' an integer to give its bit_length, hence it is defined to take self as an argument.

Comment: In other words, the docs show an equivalent (but inefficient) implementation of one of `int`'s methods, that's why it uses `self`.

Answer (score 4):

No real reason. But if you're going to monkeypatch it onto an existing class then it acts as a bit of notification for anyone that may be reading the code.

Comment: This. Since methods are just functions (well, mostly) `def do_stuff(self): ...`, `Clazz.do_stuff = do_stuff` is pretty much the same as defining a method `do_stuff` as usual, only more ugly/non-obvious/hacky and therefore not useful except when you're monkey-patching.

Comment: -1.  Incorrect.  The docs show an equivalent implementation of one of `int`'s methods, that's why it uses `self`.