# Determine function name from within that function

Tags: python, function, introspection

Is there a way to determine a function's name *from within the function*?

```
def foo():
    print("my name is", __myname__)  # <== how do I calculate this at runtime?
```

In the example above, the body of `foo` will somehow access the function name `"foo"` without hard-coding it. The output would be:

```
>>> foo()
my name is foo
```

Comment: If you're interested in tracing where print statements are coming from, also check this solution using the logging package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20112491/8305404

Answer (score 290, accepted):

If you don't want to play with the stack yourself, you should either use `"bar"` or `bar.__name__` depending on context.

Python doesn't have a feature to access the function or its name within the function itself. A magic `__function__` had been proposed for Python 3.0 but rejected. See [*PEP 3130 – Access to Current Module/Class/Function*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3130/).

The given rejection notice is:

> This PEP is rejected. It is not clear how it should be implemented or what the precise semantics should be in edge cases, and there aren't enough important use cases given. response has been lukewarm at best.

Comment: `inspect.currentframe()` is one such way.

Comment: Combining @CamHart's approach with @Yuval's avoids "hidden" and potentially deprecated methods in @RoshOxymoron's answer as well as numerical indexing into the stack for @neuro/@AndreasJung's answer: `print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)`

Comment: is it possible to summarize why its been rejected?

Comment: why is this the chosen answer? Question isn't about accessing the current function or the module itself, just the name. And the stacktrace/debugging features already have this information.

Comment: As of today, tested within my CPython 3.7.2 bar.__name__ does work. For the simplest unaccepted answer for Python 3.x + see [Vagiz Duseev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2472360/vagiz-duseev)'s answer below [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64110183/502519).

Comment: @hobs `Combining @CamHart's approach with @Yuval's avoids "hidden" and potentially deprecated methods in @RoshOxymoron's answer as well as numerical indexing into the stack for @neuro/@AndreasJung's answer` - hmm … However did you `@notify` so much guys at once ?

Comment: This answer is too old. It is now wrong. Please delete it.

Answer (score 589):

```
import inspect

def foo():
   print(inspect.stack()[0][3])
   print(inspect.stack()[1][3])  # will give the caller of foos name, if something called foo

foo()
```

output:

> ```
> foo
> <module_caller_of_foo>
> ```

Comment: You could also use:
```print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)```
or to get the caller's name:
```print(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name)```. I think it should be faster since you don't retrieve a list of all the stack frames as ```inspect.stack()``` does.

Comment: `inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` doesn't work with a decorated method whereas `inspect.stack()[0][3]` does...

Comment: Please note: inspect.stack() can incur heavy performance overhead so use sparingly! On my arm box it took 240ms to complete (for some reason)

Comment: Seems to me like something present in the Python recursion machinery might be employed to do this more efficiently

Comment: This gets the **code object's** name, not the function's name. Function names and code object names often diverge when using decorators, due to function `__name__` reassignment. The code object's name will not reflect function `__name__` changes.

Comment: @Michael please post your comment as an answer .

Comment: What is the magic number `3` in the code?

Answer (score 282):

There are few ways to get the same result:

```
import sys
import inspect

def what_is_my_name():
    print(inspect.stack()[0][0].f_code.co_name)
    print(inspect.stack()[0][3])
    print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name)
    print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name)
```

Note that the `inspect.stack` calls are thousands of times slower than the alternatives:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'inspect.stack()[0][0].f_code.co_name'
1000 loops, best of 3: 499 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'inspect.stack()[0][3]'
1000 loops, best of 3: 497 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.1 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'sys._getframe().f_code.co_name'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.135 usec per loop
```

Update 08/2021 (original post was written for Python2.7)

```
Python 3.9.1 (default, Dec 11 2020, 14:32:07)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux

python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'inspect.stack()[0][0].f_code.co_name'
500 loops, best of 5: 390 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'inspect.stack()[0][3]'
500 loops, best of 5: 398 usec per loop
python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name'
2000000 loops, best of 5: 176 nsec per loop
python -m timeit -s 'import inspect, sys' 'sys._getframe().f_code.co_name'
5000000 loops, best of 5: 62.8 nsec per loop
```

Comment: `inspect.currentframe()` seems a good tradeoff between execution time and use of private members

Comment: @mbdevpl My numbers are 1.25ms, 1.24ms, 0.5us, 0.16us normal (nonpythonic :) ) seconds accordingly (win7x64, python3.5.1)

Comment: Just so no one thinks@mbdevpl is crazy :) - I submitted an edit for the output of the 3rd run, since it didn't make any sense. No idea if the result should've been `0.100 usec` or `0.199 usec` but either way - hundreds of times faster than options 1 and 2, comparable with option 4 (though Antony Hatchkins found option 3 three times faster than option 4).

Comment: I use `sys._getframe().f_code.co_name` over `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name` simply because I have already imported the `sys` module. Is that a reasonable decision? (considering the speeds appear quite similar)

Comment: This is fullblow answer and should be the accepted one in my view

Comment: We can use `sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` to get the callers name too

Comment: `sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` does not work at all in python 3.9

Comment: What is the purpose of `from __future__ import print_function`? Works fine for me without it.

Comment: @MEMark this is legacy ;-)

Comment: using inspect is very slow like the answer suggested, I think everyone really needs to consider this.

Comment: @ManifestMan You can use `sys._getframe(1)` to access the higher frame (tested in Python 3.10) but `sys._getframe().f_back` works for me too.

Comment: The last option `sys._getframe()` invokes a private method from an other context, means you invoke a private method publicly. Notice, the `_` which is an indication for a private-accessed method. Please don't invoke it publicly!

Answer (score 74):

```
functionNameAsString = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

I wanted a very similar thing because I wanted to put the function name in a log string that went in a number of places in my code. Probably not the best way to do that, but here's a way to get the name of the current function.

Comment: Totally working, just using sys, don't need to load more modules, but not soo easy to remember it :V

Comment: Logging supports function name in the message format string.

Comment: `_` indicates a private method. Please don't invoke them publicly. You maybe want to use `inspect.currentframe()` instead which is a public method.

Comment: Well Roland, you may have a point, but look at the number of upvotes this answer got. Even I'd prefer to use this answer instead of `inspect`, which a person named gardah (a comment in an answer above) says consumed a lot of time. If the problem is with it being private, the developers need to be coaxed to provide a public function named `getCurrentFunctionName()` and `getParentFunctionName()`.

Answer (score 55):

You can get the name that it was defined with using [the approach that @Andreas Jung shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067654), but that may not be the name that the function was called with:

```
import inspect

def Foo():
   print inspect.stack()[0][3]

Foo2 = Foo

>>> Foo()
Foo

>>> Foo2()
Foo
```

Whether that distinction is important to you or not I can't say.

Comment: Same situation as with `.func_name`. Worth remembering that class names and function names in Python is one thing and variables referring to them is another.

Comment: Sometimes you may want `Foo2()` to print `Foo`. For example: `Foo2 = function_dict['Foo']; Foo2()`. In this case, Foo2 is a function pointer for perhaps a command line parser.

Comment: What kind of speed implication does this have?

Comment: Speed implication with regard to what? Is there a situation where you'd need to have this information in a hard realtime situation or something?

Answer (score 36):

I keep this handy utility nearby:

```
import inspect
myself = lambda: inspect.stack()[1][3]
```

Usage:

```
myself()
```

Comment: How would this be done with the alternative proposed here?
"myself = lambda: sys._getframe().f_code.co_name"
doesn't work (the output is "<lambda>"; I think because the result is determined at definition time, not later at call time. Hmm.

Comment: @prismalytics.io: If you call myself (myself()) and don't just use its value (myself), you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: NYCeyes was right, the name is resolved inside the lambda and thus the result is <lambda>.

The sys._getframe() and inspect.currentframe() methods MUST be executed directly inside the function you want to get the name of.

The inspect.stack() method works because you can specify the index 1, doing inspect.stack()[0][3] also yields <lambda>.

Comment: Please do not use anonymous function literal (`lambda` ...) to create a named function. Define the function the normal way using `def` and avoid multiple possible problems.

Answer (score 33):

This is actually derived from the other answers to the question.

Here's my take:

```
import sys

# for current func name, specify 0 or no argument.
# for name of caller of current func, specify 1.
# for name of caller of caller of current func, specify 2. etc.
currentFuncName = lambda n=0: sys._getframe(n + 1).f_code.co_name


def testFunction():
    print "You are in function:", currentFuncName()
    print "This function's caller was:", currentFuncName(1)    


def invokeTest():
    testFunction()


invokeTest()

# end of file
```

The likely advantage of this version over using inspect.stack() is that it should be thousands of times faster [see Alex Melihoff's post and timings regarding using sys._getframe() versus using inspect.stack() ].

Comment: Works in python 3.7

Comment: Really like this one. Easy, fast and elegant. I will balantly copy this code ^^

Answer (score 31):

I guess `inspect` is the best way to do this. For example:

```
import inspect
def bar():
    print("My name is", inspect.stack()[0][3])
```

Comment: Instead if using `inspect.stack()[0][3]`, use `inspect.stack()[0].function` which should be more robust even when semantics in stack traces change.

Answer (score 29):

I found a wrapper that will write the function name

```
from functools import wraps

def tmp_wrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        print func.__name__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return tmp

@tmp_wrap
def my_funky_name():
    print "STUB"

my_funky_name()
```

This will print

> my_funky_name
>
> STUB

Comment: As a decorator noob, I wonder if there is a way to access func.__name__ inside the context of my_funky_name (so I can retrieve its value and use it inside my_funky_name)

Comment: The way to do that inside the my_funky_name function is `my_funky_name.__name__`. You could pass the func.__name__ into the function as a new parameter. func(*args, **kwargs, my_name=func.__name__). To get your decorators name from inside your function, I think that would require using inspect. But getting the name of the function controlling my function within my running function ... well that just sounds like the start of a beautiful meme :)

Answer (score 21):

I am not sure why people make it complicated:

```
import sys 
print("%s/%s" %(sys._getframe().f_code.co_filename, sys._getframe().f_code.co_name))
```

Comment: maybe because you're using private function of sys module, outside of it. In general it is considered a bad practice, ain't it?

Comment: @tikej, the usage agrees to the best practice stated here: https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/accessing_a_protected_member_from_outside_the_class.html

Answer (score 21):

Use `__name__` attribute:

```py
# foo.py
def bar():
    print(f"my name is {bar.__name__}")
```

You can easily access function's name from within the function using `__name__` attribute.

```py
>>> def bar():
...     print(f"my name is {bar.__name__}")
...
>>> bar()
my name is bar
```

I've come across this question myself several times, looking for the ways to do it. Correct answer is contained in the Python's documentation (see [Callable types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) section).

Every function has a `__name__` parameter that returns its name and even `__qualname__` parameter that returns its full name, including which class it belongs to (see [Qualified name](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name)).

Comment: What would be the point of this if the function name "bar" would have to be known already to perform this?

Comment: @PyNoob: After renaming `bar` to `foo`, `print('bar')` happily prints (incorrectly) "bar",  whereas `print(bar.__name__)` fails.

Comment: To elaborate on @Gerhard's comment - this is useful to protect yourself later if you rename functions, because the IDE will find this reference more easily.

Comment: I still do not understand what is the point here since the name of the function - which was the whole point to avoid - is required to obtain `__name__`  . Does somene "get " this?  btw @StephenB  good point - from another StephenB[oesch]

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, we are talking about two different problems here. Gerhard gave a great example: you can use `__name__` object field of most objects, including functions, to get their name. Quite handy for logging, for example.
On the other hand, if you're injecting some code into an existing function of which you know nothing and you need to figure out its name, then you need to rely on the `inspect` module.

Answer (score 20):

`print(inspect.stack()[0].function)` seems to work too (Python 3.5).

Answer (score 18):

Here's a future-proof approach.

Combining @CamHart's and @Yuval's suggestions with @RoshOxymoron's [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5067661/623735) has the benefit of avoiding:

- `_hidden` and potentially deprecated methods
- indexing into the stack (which could be reordered in future pythons)

So I think this plays nice with future python versions (tested on 2.7.3 and 3.3.2):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import inspect

def bar():
    print("my name is '{}'".format(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name))
```

Update: tested on 3.7.10, 3.8.10, and 3.9.5

Comment: Indexing into the stack will not be reordered in future pythons.

Answer (score 15):

```
import inspect

def whoami():
    return inspect.stack()[1][3]

def whosdaddy():
    return inspect.stack()[2][3]

def foo():
    print "hello, I'm %s, daddy is %s" % (whoami(), whosdaddy())
    bar()

def bar():
    print "hello, I'm %s, daddy is %s" % (whoami(), whosdaddy())

foo()
bar()
```

In IDE the code outputs

> hello, I'm foo, daddy is
>
> hello, I'm bar, daddy is foo
>
> hello, I'm bar, daddy is

Answer (score 13):

```
import sys

def func_name():
    """
    :return: name of caller
    """
    return sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def test_class_func_name(self):
        print(func_name())

def test_func_name():
    print(func_name())
```

Test:

```
a = A()
a.test_class_func_name()
test_func_name()
```

Output:

```
test_class_func_name
test_func_name
```

Answer (score 11):

This is pretty easy to accomplish with a decorator.

```
>>> from functools import wraps

>>> def named(func):
...     @wraps(func)
...     def _(*args, **kwargs):
...         return func(func.__name__, *args, **kwargs)
...     return _
... 

>>> @named
... def my_func(name, something_else):
...     return name, something_else
... 

>>> my_func('hello, world')
('my_func', 'hello, world')
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a decorator:

```
def my_function(name=None):
    return name

def get_function_name(function):
    return function(name=function.__name__)

>>> get_function_name(my_function)
'my_function'
```

Comment: How is that answering the poster's question? Can you expand this to include an example how the function name is known from within the function?

Comment: @parvus: my answer _as is_ is an example that demonstrates an answer to OP's question

Comment: Ok, my_function is the random user's function of the OP. Blame this to my lack of understanding of decorators. Where the @? How will this work for functions whose arguments you don't want to adapt? How I understand your solution: when I want to know the function name, I have to append it with @get_function_name, and add the name argument, hoping it is not already there for another purpose. I'm likely missing something, sorry for that.

Comment: Without starting my own python course inside a comment: 1. functions are objects; 2. you could attach a name attribute to the function, print/log the name, or do any number of things with the "name" inside the decorator; 3. decorators can be attached multiple ways (e.g. @ or in my example); 4. decorators can use @wraps and/or be classes themselves; 5. I could go on, but, happy programming!

Comment: This just looks like a convoluted way to get to the `__name__` attribute of a function. The usage requires knowing the thing you are trying to get, which doesn't seem very useful to me in simple cases where functions aren't defined on the fly.

Comment: This is rather a non-answer. You just hint the very basic idea. The real usable execution of the idea is in the [answer by Jeff Laughlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788034/320437)

Comment: Downvoted - this doesn't answer the original question, and doesn't do what it states it's doing.  There are some building blocks here that could be used to construct an answer, but even then, not as useful an answer as others already given.

Answer (score 5):

I do my own approach used for calling super with safety inside multiple inheritance scenario (I put all the code)

```
def safe_super(_class, _inst):
    """safe super call"""
    try:
        return getattr(super(_class, _inst), _inst.__fname__)
    except:
        return (lambda *x,**kx: None)


def with_name(function):
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__fname__ = function.__name__
        return function(self, *args, **kwargs)
return wrap
```

sample usage:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__():
        super(A, self).__init__()

    @with_name
    def test(self):
        print 'called from A\n'
        safe_super(A, self)()

class B(object):

    def __init__():
        super(B, self).__init__()

    @with_name
    def test(self):
        print 'called from B\n'
        safe_super(B, self)()

class C(A, B):

    def __init__():
        super(C, self).__init__()

    @with_name
    def test(self):
        print 'called from C\n'
        safe_super(C, self)()
```

testing it :

```
a = C()
a.test()
```

output:

```
called from C
called from A
called from B
```

Inside each @with_name decorated method you have access to self.__fname__ as the current function name.

Answer (score 5):

I recently tried to use the above answers to access the docstring of a function from the context of that function but as the above questions were only returning the name string it did not work.

Fortunately I found a simple solution. If like me, you want to refer to the function rather than simply get the string representing the name you can apply eval() to the string of the function name.

```
import sys
def foo():
    """foo docstring"""
    print(globals()[sys._getframe().f_code.co_name].__doc__)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've updated the answer.  Let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Comment: Yes, `sys._getframe` is undocumented/implementation detail and should not be used directly.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest not to rely on stack elements. If someone use your code within different contexts (python interpreter for instance) your stack will change and break your index ([0][3]).

I suggest you something like that:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.function_name = None

    def _Handler(self, **kwargs):
        print('Calling function {} with parameters {}'.format(self.function_name, kwargs))
        self.function_name = None

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        self.function_name = attr
        return self._Handler


mc = MyClass()
mc.test(FirstParam='my', SecondParam='test')
mc.foobar(OtherParam='foobar')
```

Comment: Oh Lord, what a creative misuse of `__getattr__()` and passing of an argument as an object attribute! Please do not use this in normal (non-experimental code).

Answer (score 4):

Since`sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` does not work at all in **python 3.9**, following could be used from now:

```
from inspect import currentframe


def testNameFunction() -> str:
    return currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name


print(f'function name is {testNameFunction()}(...)')
```

Result:

```
function name is testNameFunction(...)
```

Comment: Except that the question is not about line numbers.

Comment: @MEMark i updated my answer accordently, you should have noticed the textual error, but i have also investigate the issue, and i came to the conclusion, that the call `sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name` works allthough the IDE PyCharm does not recognize it **Cannot find reference '_getframe' in 'sys.pyi | sys.pyi'**. That,s why i wrote that answer before.

Comment: @MEMark here is the post, i wrote on this issue : `https://stackoverflow.com/q/68772415/5667103`

Answer (score 4):

It seems from all the answer above that use the `inspect` library, all are writing something like:

```py
import inspect

inspect.stack()[0][3]
```

But, since the return of **`inspect.stack()[0]`** is a NamedTuple of the form:

```
FrameInfo(frame=<frame at 0x103578810, file '<stdin>', line 1, code <module>>, filename='<stdin>', lineno=1, function='<module>', code_context=None, index=None)
```

One can simply call by the name, i.e. **`inspect.stack()[0].function`**

A small dummy example can be seen here:

```
    def test_train_UGRIZY_noZ(self, architecture, dataset, hyperrun, wloss):
        log.warning(f"{inspect.stack()[0].function} -- Not Implemented Yet")
        pass
```

Which when run prints:

```
WARNING - test_train_UGRIZY_noZ -- Not Implemented Yet
```

Comment: I like being able to use `.function` to reference the function name. Unfortunately the timings for this option are still in the microsecond range, as opposed to the nanosecond range for `inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name` and `sys._getframe().f_code.co_name` as in Alex Granovsky's  answer. Also in the microsecond range: `inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).function`, but about 2x as fast as `inspect.stack()`.

Comment: It was already mentioned in a 2016 answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34665538/674039

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea of using a decorator but I'd prefer to avoid touching the function arguments. Hence, I'm providing yet another alternative:

```
import functools

def withname(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global __name
        __saved_name = globals().get("__name")
        __name = f.__name__
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        __name = __saved_name
        return ret
    return wrapper

@withname
def f():
    print(f"in f: __name=={__name}")
    g()
    print(f"back in f: __name=={__name}")

@withname
def g():
    print(f"in g: __name=={__name}")
```

We need to save and restore `__name` when calling the function as consequence of it being a global variable. Calling `f()` above produces:

```
in f: __name==f
in g: __name==g
back in f: __name==f
```

Unfortunately, there is no alternative to the `global` variable if we don't change the function arguments.  Referencing a variable, that is not created in the context of the function, will generate code that would look for a global variable:

```
>>> def f(): print(__function__)
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (__function__)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

@jeff-laughlin's answer is beautiful.  I have modified it slightly to achieve what I think is the intent: to trace out the execution of functions, and also to capture the list of arguments as well as the keyword arguments.  Thank you @jeff-laughlin!

```
from functools import wraps                                                                                                                                                                                                     
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
def named(func):                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    @wraps(func)                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    def _(*args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        print(f"From wrapper function: Executing function named: {func.__name__}, with arguments: {args}, and keyword arguments: {kwargs}.")                                                                                    
        print(f"From wrapper function: {func}")                                                                                                                                                                                 
        start_time = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                                
        return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                                                    
        end_time = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        elapsed_time = end_time - start_time                                                                                                                                                                                    
        print(f"From wrapper function: Execution of {func.__name__} took {elapsed_time} seconds.")                                                                                                                              
        return return_value                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return _                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
@named                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
def thanks(message, concepts, username='@jeff-laughlin'):                                                                                                                                                                       
    print(f"From inner function: {message} {username} for teaching me about the {concepts} concepts of closures and decorators!")                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
thanks('Thank you', 'two', username='@jeff-laughlin')                                                                                                                                                                           
print('-'*80)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
thanks('Thank you', 'two', username='stackoverflow')
print(thanks)
```

> From wrapper function: Executing function named: thanks, with arguments: ('Thank you', 'two'), and keyword arguments: {'username': '@jeff-laughlin'}.
> From wrapper function: <function thanks at 0x7f13e6ceaa60>
> From inner function: Thank you @jeff-laughlin for teaching me about the two concepts of closures and decorators!
> From wrapper function: Execution of thanks took 2.193450927734375e-05 seconds.
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> From wrapper function: Executing function named: thanks, with arguments: ('Thank you', 'two'), and keyword arguments: {'username': 'stackoverflow'}.
> From wrapper function: <function thanks at 0x7f13e6ceaa60>
> From inner function: Thank you stackoverflow for teaching me about the two concepts of closures and decorators!
> From wrapper function: Execution of thanks took 7.152557373046875e-06 seconds.
> <function thanks at 0x7f13e6ceaca0>

What is most surprising to me is that there is a way to intercept functions at runtime, inspect them, and take some actions based on this.  The other surprising thing is the memory address of the inner function was the same both times.  Does anyone know why this is?  I have a ways to go before I can understand this decorator/closure magic.

Comment: Decorator works in roughly the same way as replacing all your `thanks()` calls to `named(thanks)()`.  So the two `thanks()` calls are targeting the same function.  The wrapper function (underscore (`_`)) is dynamically instantiated (and soon destroied) everytime.

Comment: By the way, if you put some `print(_)` calls before `return _`, you will see the output upon every `@named` call. `print()` can be added between `def` for better understanding.  In Python, almost all things happen in run time, including function "declarations", which creates a function object and registers it to current namespace.

Answer (score 1):

implementing your own decorator

#foo.py

```
from mydecorators import *

@print_my_name
def bar():
    #do something else
    pass
#in terminal: my name is: bar
```

#mydecorators.py

```
def resolve_function(func):
    #in case annotated func is an staticmethod
    if isinstance(func,staticmethod):
        return func.__func__
    return func

def print_my_name(func):
    def function_caller(*args,**kwargs):
        _func = resolve_function(func)
        print("my name is: %s" %_func.__name__)
        return _func(*args,**kwargs)
    return function_caller
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str(str(inspect.currentframe())).split(' ')[-1][:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import inspect


def method_name():
    return inspect.stack()[1][3]


def method_name_caller():
    return inspect.stack()[2][3]


def asdf():
    print(method_name_caller())
    print(method_name())


def asdf2():
    print(method_name_caller())
    print(method_name())
    asdf()
```