# Python Logging (function name, file name, line number) using a single file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am trying to learn how an application works. And for this I am inserting debug commands as the first line of each function's body with the goal of logging the function's name as well as the line number (within the code) where I send a message to the log output. Finally, since this application comprises of many files, I want to create a single log file so that I can better understand the control flow of the application.

Here is what I know:

1. for getting function name, I can use `function_name.__name__` but I don't want to use the function_name (so that I could rapidly copy and paste a generic `Log.info("Message")` in the body of all functions). I know this could be done in C using `__func__` macro but I am not sure about python.
2. for getting the filename and line number, I have seen that (and I believe that) my application is using Python `locals()` function but in a syntax that I am not completely aware of e.g.: `options = "LOG.debug('%(flag)s : %(flag_get)s' % locals())` and I tried it using like `LOG.info("My message %s" % locals())` which produces something like `{'self': <__main__.Class_name object at 0x22f8cd0>}`. Any input on this please?
3. I know how to use logging and add handler to it to log to a file but I am not sure if a single file can be used to record all log messages in correct order of function calls in the project.

Comment: You can drop into the python debugger by using `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, and then step through code interactively. That may help you trace program flow.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks Matt. It would still be helpful to get a log as mentioned in the question so that I don't have to debug every time. Also, do you know of an IDE for python which is as good as Eclipse for Java (ctrl+click takes you to function definition) that I can make use of to make debugging easier ?

Comment: What is the **question** here?

Comment: Anyone visiting this question in 2022 and beyond... dont use pdb. Its a fine library if the only IDE you have is vim, but if you have a modern IDE such as VSCode or Pycharm, the debugging suites there are more than capable of providing this information without littering your code with unnecessary lines that could potentially be a source of problems if left in.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have a few marginally related questions here.

I'll start with the easiest: (3). Using `logging` you can aggregate all calls to a single log file or other output target: they will be in the order they occurred in the process.

Next up: (2). `locals()` provides a dict of the current scope. Thus, in a method that has no other arguments, you have `self` in scope, which contains a reference to the current instance. The trick being used that is stumping you is the string formatting using a dict as the RHS of the `%` operator. `"%(foo)s" % bar` will be replaced by whatever the value of `bar["foo"]` is.

Finally, you can use some introspection tricks, similar to those used by `pdb` that can log more info:

```
def autolog(message):
    "Automatically log the current function details."
    import inspect, logging
    # Get the previous frame in the stack, otherwise it would
    # be this function!!!
    func = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code
    # Dump the message + the name of this function to the log.
    logging.debug("%s: %s in %s:%i" % (
        message, 
        func.co_name, 
        func.co_filename, 
        func.co_firstlineno
    ))
```

This will log the message passed in, plus the (original) function name, the filename in which the definition appears, and the line in that file. Have a look at [inspect - Inspect live objects](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) for more details.

As I mentioned in my comment earlier, you can also drop into a `pdb` interactive debugging prompt at any time by inserting the line `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in, and re-running your program. This enables you to step through the code, inspecting data as you choose.

Comment: Thanks Matt ! I will try this autolog function. I have a little confusion regarding the using dict as RHS of % operator: Would `'%(foo)s : %(bar)s'` would also print the `bar["foo"]`'s value ? Or is it somewhat different than your example ?

Comment: Basically, everything of the form `%(<foo>)s` is replaced by the value of the object referenced in the dict by `<foo>`. There are more examples/detail at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: @synthesizerpatel 's answer is much more helpful.

Answer (score 703):

The correct answer for this is to use the already provided [`funcName`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) variable

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
FORMAT = "[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)20s() ] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Then anywhere you want, just add:

```
logger.debug('your message')
```

Example output from a script I'm working on right now:

```
[invRegex.py:150 -          handleRange() ] ['[A-Z]']
[invRegex.py:155 -     handleRepetition() ] [[<__main__.CharacterRangeEmitter object at 0x10ba03050>, '{', '1', '}']]
[invRegex.py:197 -          handleMacro() ] ['\\d']
[invRegex.py:155 -     handleRepetition() ] [[<__main__.CharacterRangeEmitter object at 0x10ba03950>, '{', '1', '}']]
[invRegex.py:210 -       handleSequence() ] [[<__main__.GroupEmitter object at 0x10b9fedd0>, <__main__.GroupEmitter object at 0x10ba03ad0>]]
```

Comment: Great..
One thing to add, can we name the logfile to be same as codefile dynamically?
eg:
I tried 
logging.basicConfig(filename= "%(filename)", format=FORMAT)
to take filename dynamically, but it took static value. any suggestion?

Comment: @Outlier No, the recommended way to achieve that is via `getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: I have one question: In Java somewhere I read that printing the line number is discouraged as it takes extra time to figure out from which line the logger is being called. In python this isn't true?

Comment: how can i also put the caller in the `FORMAT`?

Comment: Irrelevant, but `logging.getLogger('root')` isn't what you're expecting probably, it's not the `root` logger, but an ordinary logger with name 'root'.

Comment: Recommend updating answer to link to https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes for viewing all available placeholders.

Comment: Accept this please

Comment: What does `20s()` in `%(funcName)20s()` do?

Comment: @hipoglucido I think it formats 20 spaces, right justified.

Answer (score 15):

I like the answer given by @synthesizerpatel but I like this format better to include the level name

```
FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s %(filename)s->%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s]%(levelname)s: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)
```

Results in something like:

```
[2022-04-25 11:00:50,885 main.py->loop():21]INFO: looping
```

For point 3, you can log to a file using `filename` in the basic config:

```
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO, filename='main.log')
```

but I prefer to setup a rotating log file so it doesn't grow uncontrolled with RotatingFileHandler. It will also show up in the console at the same time as writing to the log file

Full example `main.py`

```
import logging                                                                                         
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler                                                       
import time                                                                                            
                                                                                                       
#Setup logger                                                                                          
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)                                                                   
FORMAT = "[%(asctime)s %(filename)s->%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s]%(levelname)s: %(message)s"             
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, level=logging.INFO)                                                 
#Log to file                                                                                           
logging_filename = 'main.log'                                                                          
handler = RotatingFileHandler(logging_filename, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=10) #10 files of 1MB each
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(FORMAT))                                                        
logger.addHandler(handler)                                                                             
                                                                                                       
def main():                                                                                            
  while True:                                                                                        
    loop()                                                                                         
    time.sleep(1)                                                                                  
                                                                                                       
def loop():                                                                                            
  logger.info('looping')                                                                             
                                                                                                       
if __name__== "__main__":                                                                              
  main()
```

Answer (score 12):

`funcname`, `linename` and `lineno` provide information about the last function that did the logging.

If you have wrapper of logger (e.g singleton logger), then @synthesizerpatel's answer might not work for you.

To find out the other callers in the call stack you can do:

```
import logging
import inspect

class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class MyLogger(metaclass=Singleton):
    logger = None

    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(
            level=logging.INFO,
            format="%(asctime)s - %(threadName)s - %(message)s",
            handlers=[
                logging.StreamHandler()
            ])

        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__ + '.logger')

    @staticmethod
    def __get_call_info():
        stack = inspect.stack()

        # stack[1] gives previous function ('info' in our case)
        # stack[2] gives before previous function and so on

        fn = stack[2][1]
        ln = stack[2][2]
        func = stack[2][3]

        return fn, func, ln

    def info(self, message, *args):
        message = "{} - {} at line {}: {}".format(*self.__get_call_info(), message)
        self.logger.info(message, *args)
```

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I needed to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Since Python 3.8, the `logging` class supports stack level skipping out-of-the-box: methods like `log()`, `debug()`, etc. now accept a `stacklevel` argument. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug).