# HTML Logger in python

Tags: python, logging

I am using python `logging module` for logging to console and text file. I am using `HTMLTestRunner` for logging in html file. I guess I am using HTMLTestRunner 0.8.0

However problem is that `HTMLTestRunner` prints only `print` statements and logging module does not print print statements. Is there any way I can get logging statement inside html file

Below is the htmlrunner code

```
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
                stream=outfile,
                title='Test Report',
                description='Regression Test Suite',
                verbosity=3
                )
result = runner.run(suite)
```

Edited : I am using `import unittest`, and for logging I am using `import logging`. For HTML runner I am using `import HTMLTestRunner`

For printing statements on the console, I am using `logging.info` and `logging.debug`. If I use print statements using python `print`, then I am neither getting this output in the console nor in the logs. But for HTML logging, I am having only `print` statements and `stderr`.

My query : Is there someway that  `HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner` will have statements which are printed on the console using `logging.debug` and `logging.info`

Comment: I'd love to try to help, but I don't see enough information to go on. Which `HTMLTestRunner` are you using: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/HTMLTestRunner, or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-testRunner/, or something else?  Show us an example fixture, with an example of the logger statements, what you want to see from `HTMLTestRunner`, and what you actually see.

Comment: @JimDeLaHunt: I have edited the question. Please let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: The additional detail helps. But please also show us an actual test case, with actual logging and `print` statements. Show us the output you get, and the output you expect.

Comment: "print statements" don't do anything special. They just write to stdout. What you want is adding a `logging` handler so that it prints everything on stdout (you may not want to enable this during normal execution of your program, just tests)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`HTMLTestRunner`](https://github.com/tungwaiyip/HTMLTestRunner) module that you are currently using is about 6 years old and is seriously out of date. There are better options - starting from the [`html-testRunner`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-testRunner/) or, even a better one - `pytest` with the [HTML reporting plugin](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html) enabled.

But, if you are ready to patch/change the `HTMLTestRunner` implementation, here is what we need to do to make the logging work and messages displayed in the report (this is just one way to do it):

- add a new `logger` argument to the `HTMLTestRunner` class constructor and attach a new handler to the logger:

  ```
  class HTMLTestRunner(Template_mixin):
      def __init__(self, stream=sys.stdout, verbosity=1, title=None, description=None, logger=None):  # CHANGE HERE
          # ...

          # CHANGE BELOW
          self.log_capture = None
          if logger:
              self.log_capture = StringIO.StringIO()

              ch = logging.StreamHandler(self.log_capture)
              ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

              formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
              ch.setFormatter(formatter)

              logger.addHandler(ch)
  ```
- edit the `HEADING_TMPL` template and add a placeholder for the logging messages:

  ```
  HEADING_TMPL = """<div class='heading'>
  <h1>%(title)s</h1>
  %(parameters)s
  <p class='description'>%(description)s</p>
  Logging output:
  <p class='logs'>%(logs)s</p>
  </div>
  """ # variables: (title, parameters, description)
  ```
- change the `_generate_heading()` method and fill out the `logs` placeholder:

  ```
  heading = self.HEADING_TMPL % dict(
      title = saxutils.escape(self.title),
      parameters = ''.join(a_lines),
      description = saxutils.escape(self.description),
      logs='<br>'.join(self.log_capture.getvalue().split("\n")) if self.log_capture else ""
  )
  ```
- don't forget the `import logging`

Now, if you have, for instance, this kind of test with a `logger` instance writing log messages in the tests, you can pass the logger into the `HTMLTestRunner` which would then dump the log messages into the report:

```
import logging
import unittest

import HTMLTestRunner

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class BasicTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):
        logger.info('Test message 1!')
        self.assertEqual(1, 1)

    def test_two(self):
        """Extended description"""
        logger.error('Test message 1!')
        self.assertEqual(2, 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

    with open('report.html', 'w') as report_file:
        runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
            stream=report_file,
            title='Test Report',
            description='Regression Test Suite',
            verbosity=3,
            logger=logger
        )

        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(BasicTestCase)

        result = runner.run(suite)
        print(result)
```

Contents of the `report.html` after running the test:

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution it worked. But all the logging info output is getting printed outside the table. Like in your case too, you have 2 test cases but logging info is getting printed at the top of the table. Is it possible to get the logging.info of respective test case in the table. Example: if I click detail of basicTestCase, then logging info related to test case 1 should be displayed in testcase1 detail. same for test case-2. Is it possible

Comment: @Nitesh yeah, put it into the header for sample purposes. To have logs in the table rows, you should first of all modify the [`REPORT_CLASS_TMPL` template](https://github.com/tungwaiyip/HTMLTestRunner/blob/master/HTMLTestRunner.py#L462) to allow for logs written into a table row - you would need a placeholder for logs. Then, you would need to fill out the placeholder [here](https://github.com/tungwaiyip/HTMLTestRunner/blob/master/HTMLTestRunner.py#L740). Okay, but that's just a preparation step.

Comment: @Nitesh then, you would need to figure out a way to group logging messages per test method. You can probably construct log message strings  so that they would contain a test method name - check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10973362/771848). Then, you would need the output of the `self.log_capture.getvalue().split("\n")` to be parsed and grouped per test method. I hope you can understand my thinking here. I suggest you start a new topic on SO if you need help with implementing the idea. That said, again, switching to a more modern reporter would be easier. Thanks.