# How can I tell what function called my function?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm just wondering if I have code of the form:

```
def f1()
  return f2()

def f2()
  print(this.calling_function())
```

What can I put in `this.calling_function()` to get it to print `f1` as the answer?

(In other words, how can I go one level up in the stack trace).

Comment: You can go up the stack, but the calling function doesn't know it's name either.

Comment: This is a combination of [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5067604) and `sys._getframe(1)`.

Comment: The most detailed dulicate of this topic I found was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/python-how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method

Comment: Why do you want to know?  Normally, a function should not care who is calling it.

Comment: If it's important to you, why not pass it as a parameter, rather than mucking about