# Why is inspect.currentframe slower than sys. _getframe?

Tags: python

Following up on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17366561/1982118

On my macbook pro 2015 (2.8 GHz Intel Core i7) with python 3.6, I get:

```
python3 -m timeit -s 'import inspect' 'inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name'
>>> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.428 usec per loop

python3 -m timeit -s 'import sys' 'sys._getframe().f_code.co_name'

>>> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.114 usec per loop
```

using sys._getframe() is 4 times faster than inspect.currentframe().

How come?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the question is about CPython, you can see the implementation of `inspect.currentframe` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py):

```
def currentframe():
    """Return the frame of the caller or None if this is not possible."""
    return sys._getframe(1) if hasattr(sys, "_getframe") else None
```

The function calls `hasattr` in addition to `sys._getframe`, thus it *has* to be slower.

`hasattr` works by attempting to get the attribute and catching the `AttributeError` exception, if that fails. The `_getframe` attribute exists and is retrieved *again*, thus adding to the overhead.

Comment: Additionally, `getattr(foo, "bar")` is often slower than `foo.bar` (~2x on my machine), I believe because it has to do more work at runtime rather than when compiling bytecode, so you pay more than double for checking twice.