# Determine function name from within an aliased function

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

How can I determine whether a function was called using the function's name or by the name of an alias of that function?

I can inspect a function to get its name from within the body of a function by doing:

```
import inspect

def foo():
   print(inspect.stack()[0][3])

foo() # prints 'foo'
```

source: [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5067604/5992438)

However, if I alias the function and try the same thing I get the original function name (not the alias)

```
bar = foo
bar() # prints 'foo'
```

I would like to be able to be able to do the following:

```
def foo():
    print(... some code goes here ...)

bar = foo

foo() # prints 'foo'
bar() # prints 'bar'
```

Comment: There's no guarantee the reference used to call your function was obtained from any name at all. It could have been `l = [foo]; l[0]()` or `sorted(some_list, key=l[0])`.

Comment: That's a good point, I guess in that case `l[0]()` should print `l[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a (somewhat hacky) solution that relies on a regex to parse the function name out of a string. There might be a cleaner solution, but at least using inspect only this is the best I could find.

```
import inspect
import re


function_from_call = re.compile("\w+(?=\(\))")


def foo():
    _, call_frame, *_ = inspect.stack()
    _, _, _, _, call, *_ = call_frame
    print(re.search(function_from_call, str(call)).group())

bar = foo
bar()  # prints bar
foo()  # prints foo
```

Short explanation: First, I am grabbing the inspect frame of the call that resulted in a call to this function. Then, I am extracting the actual call string from this frame and I apply a regex to this call string that gives us the function name only.

Note: From an interpreter shell, inspect behaves differently and my code above produces an error because my regex cannot match an actual function name. An additional caveat is pointed out in a comment to this question by @user2357112: It is not obvious that a call is directly tied to a name, as in

```
l = [foo]; l[0]()
```

When run from a script, my solution will handle simple renaming cases properly (as the one given in this question) but I do not advocate using it since corner cases as the one above will result in confusing errors.

Comment: I'm really curious to see this working! But your regexp doesn't match anything for me.

Comment: that's odd. did you use my code exactly as provided here? I get the print output as commented. I am using Python 3.5.2. in case that plays into it somehow.. Edit and Note: I am not sure that my regexp can handle arbitrarily named functions as is (which is why I called it a "hack" above).

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.2, the inspect module might be slightly different

Comment: And when I use inspect.stack(), as expected, the function name is still foo.

Comment: I installed Python 3.6.2 in a pyenv but running my script with it still gives me my described output..mysterious. But notice that the answer of @JacobIRR (which gets around the regex) uses the same inspect access as I do.

Comment: I find it extremely puzzling that it works. It really shouldn't... I'll investigate

Comment: It doesn't work in the interpreter but does as a script.

Comment: Yes, good catch. I can reproduce your problem in the interpreter. 
I guess that is an intricacy of inspect. I will edit to make people aware of this.

Comment: I am truly amazed by the solution you both came up with.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me as well. It is a little hacky but I don't imagine a non-hacky solution to this problem is available.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the limited knowledge I have of the scope of your problem, this works:

```
import inspect

def foo():
  print(inspect.stack()[1][4][0].strip())

foo()
bar = foo
bar()
```

Results:

```
foo()
bar()
```

Comment: This raises a 'NoneType not subscriptable' error for me. I can make it work by using inspect.stack()[0][3] instead, but then it still returns 'foo'. Any idea how you could actually make this work?

Comment: It doesn't work in the interpreter but does as a script.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me (both in an interpreter and in a script with python3.6) and has the added benefit of giving the arguments in the parentheses as well.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, yuck.. Seems like any solution to this would be hacky. The only other thing I can think of is to loop through all parts of the stack and print the function name if it is NOT the name of the original, but still a hack

Comment: @JacobIRR Well I am actually truly amazed that you could make it work as hacky as it is, good job!

Comment: This solution also works for the case outlined by @user2357112 in the comment on the question: `l = [foo()]; l[0]()`, prints `'l[0]()'`