# In python3, how can one reference a function from within the scope of that function without knowing the name of the function?

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a function:

```
def foo():
    """foo docstring"""
    print(foo.__doc__)
```

How can I write this, without using the function name `foo` within the print function?

Please note I've read through this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback/5067654), which allows access to the name of a function as a string, but as far as I can see does not give access to the function itself.

Comment: And... why?  What utility is there is a mechanism for a function not to know its own name?

Comment: @StephenRauch quite simply because a function is an object and just like other objects it doesn't really have a name. If after `foo` definition you add `bar = foo; foo = None; bar()`, then you will not get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I expected.  To access the function itself instead of just the name, apply eval() to the name.

```
import inspect

def foo():
    """zxy"""
    print(fself().__doc__)

def fself():
    """returns parent function when called"""
    return eval(inspect.stack()[1][3])

def bar():
    """abcdefg"""
    print(fself().__doc__)

bar()
foo()
```

This code produces:

```
>abcdefg
>zxy
```

The great thing is I can now use this as a module and access fself in other scripts.