# Determine line number in Python 3.9

Tags: python

Since`sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno` does not work at all in **python 3.9**, following could be used from now:

```
from inspect import currentframe


def testLineNumberFunction() -> int:
    return currentframe().f_back.f_lineno


print(f'line number is {testLineNumberFunction()}')
```

Result:

```
line number is 8
```

**Is there a faster way to achieve this ?**

Because the library **inspect** seems to be **slow** as mentioned here [by @AlexGranovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17366561/5667103)

Comment: Do you only need the name, and not other information like line number, etc? If so, why not `my_function.__name__`, or just explicitly use the string `'my_function'`?

Comment: @Brian right, it was about line number, i did update the question accordently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly access f_code, don't do f_back.f_code

This will give you function name as in heading

```
import sys

def f1():
    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name

print(f1())
```

```
f1
```

```py
Python 3.9.5 (default, May 27 2021, 19:45:35) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> 
>>> def f1():
...     return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
... 
>>> print(f1())
f1
>>>
```

Comment: Wow this is crazy, i have tested in Pycharm with the Python 3.8.8 and Python 3.9, from my IDE, it does not recognize the command at all :|

Comment: i updated the question i type the wrong question, it was supposed to be about line number not the name, but i just wanted to know why my IDE does not recognize it at all. Thanks for your answer it did help me, it works allthough the IDE does not recognize it `Cannot find reference '_getframe' in 'sys.pyi | sys.pyi'`