# How to get the name of function in if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get the name of function in `if` statement?
Is there any easy solution?
My case:

```
if is_wedge(df):
    fname = is_wedge.__name__
    img_path = Path(main_dir / 'images' / fname / img1.jpeg')
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. Try [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback)

Comment: `print(my_function.__name__)`

Comment: @anosha_rehan: Not a dup — there's nothing indicating this code is inside a function.

Comment: @jfaccioni: If one knows enough to write `my_function.__name__` then obviously one already knows the name of the function.

Comment: @jfaccioni without write 'my_function'

Comment: Batjl: Your question makes little sense — how could the `print` know it was being called because some function returned `True` when it was called earlier?

Comment: @martineau well yes, but the function is already known anyway if you're calling it in the `if` statement...

Comment: @jfaccioni: That only reinforces my point.

Comment: Very strange requirement, can you explain an example use-case?

Comment: Still not very clear. Is `is_wedge.__name__` not an option?

Comment: @matszwecja yes

Comment: Care to elaborate why?

Comment: `is_wedge` ≠ `iswedge`. Question still not making much sense. Also looks like OP is using pandas but hasn't mention it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine function name from within that function (without using traceback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function-without-using-traceback)

Answer (score 0):

Could you use inspect.stack?

```
import inspect

def iswedge():
    stack = inspect.stack()    # Get stack info
    caller_info = stack[0]    # Get caller info
    fname = caller_info[3]    # Get function name
    img_path = Path(main_dir / 'images' / fname / img1.jpeg')
```