# Determine function name from within that function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, introspection

The Problem was :

- ... title : Determine function name (module) from within that function in Python
- In my context of Test Unit but in any other
- without decorator sugar if possible (before industrialisation)

Related to : [Determine function name from within that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067604/determine-function-name-from-within-that-function)

But: the impossibility to

- comment <= poor reputation
- add a response <= no reputation
- react to a very old then active,
  but fragmented answered question...
- feed with this test case !!!

```py
def test_A_01__techreq__labelling__by_introspection():
    from_globals = globals()
    from_globals__co_name = from_globals[sys._getframe().f_code.co_name]
    from_globals__co_name__testcase_module_name = from_globals__co_name.__module__
    from_globals__co_name__testcase_name = from_globals__co_name.__name__

    from_inspect_code = inspect.currentframe().f_code
    from_inspect_code__co_filename = from_inspect_code.co_filename
    from_inspect_code__co_filename__but_basename_testcase_module_name = Path(from_inspect_code__co_filename).name
    from_inspect_code__co_name__testcase_name = from_inspect_code.co_name

    print(
        f"\nTestcase Via globals() : "
        f"module={from_globals__co_name__testcase_module_name} : "
        f"name={from_globals__co_name__testcase_name}")
    print(
        f"Testcase Via inspects() : "
        f"module={from_inspect_code__co_filename__but_basename_testcase_module_name} : "
        f"name={from_inspect_code__co_name__testcase_name}")

    assert from_globals__co_name__testcase_module_name == "tests.test_05_archi_builder"
    assert from_inspect_code__co_filename__but_basename_testcase_module_name == "test_05_archi_builder.py"
    assert from_globals__co_name__testcase_name == from_inspect_code__co_name__testcase_name == "test_A_01__techreq__labelling__by_introspection"
```

```yaml
test_05_archi_builder.py::test_A_01__techreq__labelling__by_introspection PASSED [100%]
Testcase Via globals() : module=tests.test_05_archi_builder : name=test_A_01__techreq__labelling__by_introspection
Testcase Via inspects() : module=test_05_archi_builder.py : name=test_A_01__techreq__labelling__by_introspection
```

Comment: this looks like a copy / past from a school test with no attempt made.